# Gradient effect IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, gradient

I'm using following CSS to give gradient effect to the backGround but in IE it doesn't work.  how can i make it work in IE8?

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #000000, #829a90);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(#000000),to(#829a90) );
```

Comment: Might not answer your question but it maybe worth a look http://css3pie.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tested on IE8 and its working:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000000', 
                                  endColorstr='#829a90');
```

Also there are some limitations in giving gradient effect in IE because it doesn't supports color-stop and radial gradient. Also it's not guaranteed that all the browsers will support gradients thats why you shouldn't rely on gradient.

Comment: @Quasdunk: What does the link do?

Comment: @Harry Joy You can paste a css-declaration in there, for instance `background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #000000, #829a90);`, then click on the Prefixize-button and it shows you the declaration for nearly all browsers.